# Как убирать debug код из релизной версии?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Какие инструмены используются в web-разработке, чтобы убирать debug код из продакшен-релиза?

Я хочу переключать состояния в компоненах, с помощью хука `useEffect`, но не хочу, чтобы он попал в релиз.

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ...` - обычное дело, вроде)) Чтобы не перевычислять каждый раз, можно свойством в корневой компонент засунуть, если реакт предусматривает аналог вьюшного `this.$root`.

Comment: @yar85 Я новичек, спасибо. Попробую как вы сказали.